# Soddy Line in Slope Intercept Form

Tags: soddy-circles

Given three coordinates of a triangle, is there a simple technique for representing that triangle's [Soddy Line](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SoddyLine.html) in slope intercept form?

Edit:  One of the points on the line (incenter), is super obvious.  I guess if any of the other points on the line described in the link are similarly simple to calculate, then I would have a simple solution.